# How do they run these commands in python console within Django project?

Tags: python, django, console

How do they run these python commands in python console within their django project. Here is [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/overview/#enjoy-the-free-api).

I'm using Windows 10, PyCharm and python 3.7. I know how to run the project. But when I run the project, - console opens, which gives regular input/output for the project running.
When I open python console - I can run commands, so that they execute immidiately, but how do I run python console, so that I can type some commands and they would execute immediately, but that would happen within some project?

Example from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/overview/#enjoy-the-free-api):

```
# Import the models we created from our "news" app
>>> from news.models import Article, Reporter

# No reporters are in the system yet.
>>> Reporter.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>

# Create a new Reporter.
>>> r = Reporter(full_name='John Smith')

# Save the object into the database. You have to call save() explicitly.
>>> r.save()

# Now it has an ID.
>>> r.id
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the project you're using a management command: `python manage.py runserver`. To enter a console that has access to all your Django apps, the ORM, etc., use another management command: `python manage.py shell`. That will allow you to import models as shown in your example.

As an additional tip, consider installing the [Django extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) package, which includes a management command `shell_plus`. It's helpful, especially (but not only) in development, as it imports all your models, along with some other handy tools.

Answer (score 1):

Django has a [Shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#shell) management command that allows you to open a Python shell with all the Django stuff bootstrapped and ready to be executed.

So by using `./manage.py shell` you will get an interactive python shell where you can write code.

Comment: You can run `manage.py shell` [inside PyCharm Professional Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-manage-py.html), and you [could try to set up something similar](https://hirelofty.com/blog/configuring-pycharm-debug-django-shell/) in PyCharm community edition. However I recommend that you get used to running the `manage.py` commands outside of PyCharm to begin with, and then think about running them inside PyCharm for convenience later.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this:

In the Menu bar, go to **Tools -> Run manage.py Task**
[image: Menu]

You'll see the results of running that command in a console below. Run your commands here.

[image: console]